# Why am I losing share access to my LUNS?

Tags: windows-server-2003, share, lun

Question Rephrased:

On our NAS, I have 3 LUNS created (I do not know if this is the cause of the problem).

On my DC, I have attached them using iScsi, and have created them as a disk. On that Disk I created folders so my users can access and use.

For each folder, the Sharing settings are for Everyone: R/W
[image]
[image]

After some time (noticed more after reboots) everyone looses access to the drives. What I need to do in order to bring it back is: 
Check the checkbox for: Do not share this folder.
Press OK.
And than check the : Share this folder.
This I need to do for every folder on the drive.

The security settings I have are for Authenticated Users full control.
[image]

Why is it happening?

Comment: You've given us almost zero information here, seriously, how on earth could we answer this, just no details whatsoever. I'll close the question very soon if you don't add more.

Comment: I don't see how LUNs are relevant here yet the acronym appears both in the question title and 3 times in the question.

Comment: I have edited the question to give as much information as I can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that our NAS that hosts the LUNS, had a scheduled restart every Sunday morning. And the server does not refreshes the links to the attached LUNS.

I have cancelled the restarts, and now all is well.

Comment: Who can be so crazy to schedule a weekly restart on a SAN?!? :-O

Comment: Whoever it is, he must be related to the [BOFH](http://www.theregister.co.uk/odds/bofh/) somehow.